# View not working when window is closed - how to fix this issue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, view

Hello I have a view which is shown when a button is pressed this works fine, if I open a second window the view works fine and I can go back the prior window and use the view as I have used removeFromSuperview.

My problem is however if I close the last opened window the view no longer works on the first window, however if I open a new window it works on the first window again.

How do I get the view to continue working when one of the windows have been closed?

Thanks for your help!

Here is the code I am using:

```
-(IBAction) ShowView:(id) sender{
    [myView setHidden:FALSE];

    if ([myView isInFullScreenMode]){
        [myView exitFullScreenModeWithOptions:nil];

    }
    else{   
        [myView enterFullScreenMode:[[myView window] screen] withOptions:nil];

        for (NSView *view in [NSArray arrayWithArray:[myView subviews]]){
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            [myView addSubview:view];
        }
    }
}
```